# Windows 10 Upgrade no x button

Tags: windows-10-desktop

Hello can somebody help me? how to force close this windows 10 upgrade i already off the windows update or check if i want. AND THERE IS NO X BUTTON.

here.
[image]

things that i tried:
1. Close by windows task manager.
2. End process the GSW.exe.

if by chance that i restart my pc does the windows 10 will install?

[image]

please help me! i dont want to install that windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schedule upgrade for later. Then you can cancel it.

[Microsoft documentation for upgrade](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3095675)

However Windows 10 is ok